# Use content custom filter for all shortcodes

Tags: filters, shortcode

I have tried many hooks trying to manipulate the processed content coming from of all the shortcodes, customize it, and output the final result on the pages

I have no idea what shortcodes are, so I would like to execute a filter or something that works on every shortcode

How this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so I would like to execute a filter or something that works on every shortcode

Looks like you're after [do_shortcode_tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/do_shortcode_tag/). It "Filters the output created by a shortcode callback.".

[Aurovrata Venet](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/do_shortcode_tag/#comment-2079) gives a demo usage similar to:

```
add_filter( 'do_shortcode_tag',function ($output, $tag, $attr){

  //make sure it is the right shortcode
  if('aShortcode' != $tag){ 
    return $output;
  }

  //you can even check for specific attributes
  if(!isset($attr['id'])){ 
    return $output;
  }

  $output .= '.. do somthing ..';

  return $output;
},10,3);
```